# Passing in a function with different arity to lists:map in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Let's say that I want to go over a list of integers using `lists:map` and I want that map to return a list with the same length with only numbers greater than a certain value. This is how I can achieve it now:

```
f(Min) ->
    List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    lists:map(fun(N) -> max(N, Min) end, List).
```

A rough idea of what I wished was possible is:

```
f(Min) ->
    List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    lists:map(fun erlang:max/2 (Min), List).
```

Is there a way to pass in a function with arity greater than 1 as the first argument of the `lists:map` function?

Comment: You can't pass a function with more than one arity to `lists:map`, but you can close over it with a single-arity function (you have already done it in the first snippet). However, see my answer as to why you shouldn't use `lists:map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use list comprehension or `lists:filter` for this case:

```
NewList = [N || N <- List, N > Min]
```

Or

```
NewList = lists:filter(fun(N) -> N > Min end, List)
```

However, if you really prefer using `lists:map`, you will need to take into consideration to return something when `N` is less than or equal to `Min`.

```
f1(N, Min) when N > Min -> N;
f1(N, Min) when N =< Min -> undefined.  % return 'undefined'

myfun(Min, List) -> lists:map(fun(N) -> f1(N, Min) end, List).
```

As you can see, you can "close over" any function with any number of arity with closure.

You will end up with a list of with all the numbers less than `N` replaced by `undefined` followed by those more than `N`.

```
> myfun(5, [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]).
> [undefined, undefined, undefined, 6, 7]
```

`lists:map` concerns with mapping of values `X -> X'`, not filtering a list's members.

Comment: This is my [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what I wished to do. In reality, I wish to maintain all elements in the list, but replace invalid elements (in this example, below `Min`) with something I can take as input. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @goncalotomas and that's appreciated. However, you should edit your question to make it clearer. This sentence "...return a list with only numbers greater than a certain value..." implies filtering. Also, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: You're right. That part was poorly worded and I've edited the question again. My main focus here is knowing about language constructs that allow me to pass in functions to `lists:map` or `lists:filter` with more arguments than usually permitted (assuming the extra arguments do not change), without having to use an anonymous function as a wrapper.

Comment: Unless a language supports flexible arity i.e. named arguments like in Python, you can't do that without using a lambda. But what make you not want to use it? It's the core feature of any functional language.

Answer (score 2):

> I wish to maintain all elements in the list, but replace invalid
>   elements (in this example, below Min) with something I can take as
>   input

Using a different syntax than Pie 'Oh' Pah's answer:

```
my_map(Target, Repl, Nums) ->
    lists:map(
        fun(Num) when Num =< Target  -> Repl;
           (Num)                     -> Num
        end,
        Nums
    ).
```

In the shell:

```
15> c(f1).
f1.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,f1}

16> f1:my_map(3, "-", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).
["-","-","-",4,5]

17> f1:my_map(
         fun(X) -> 10 end, 
         [a, {b,c}], 
         [100, a, make_ref(), spawn(fun() -> 2 end), 
          {x, 1}, #{a=>1,b=>2}, [1,2,3]
         ]
    ). 
[[a,{b,c}],
 [a,{b,c}],
 [a,{b,c}],
 <0.68.0>,
 {x,1},
 #{a => 1,b => 2},
 [1,2,3]]
```